# Configure iptables to set default gateway for local network

Tags: iptables, local-area-network

I have an openwrt router with ip 192.168.1.1. What I want to do is to set a proxy server (192.168.1.249) in LAN, and intercepts all communicaitons from two devices (192.168.1.244, 192.168.1.131). The method I use is to set the proxy server as the default gateway, and I configured the following things on my openwrt router.

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j MARK --set-mark 3 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.131
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j MARK --set-mark 3 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.244
# Set default gateway as the proxy server in table 2
ip route add default via 192.168.1.249 table 2
# Forward traffic with mark 3 to table 2
ip rule add fwmark 3 table 2
```

After my test, for all WAN communicaitons of the two devices, the proxy server can intercept them and forward them, it's good. **However, I found that these two devices also communicate with each other, and these LAN communications seems not to be forwarded to the proxy server**. What is the reason? How can I forward these traffic to the proxy server?

**TEST**: In order to figure out whether configuring iptables is useful, I added a rule for testing:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j DROP -s 192.168.1.131
```

In my opinoin, if this rule works, then the device with ip 244 will not receive any traffic from device with ip 131, and this proves that iptables can work for LAN communication. However, I used the 131 device to send tcp traffic to 244 device, and it works. I doubt that configuring iptables cannot help me forward these LAN traffic to my proxy server. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your IP subnet is `192.168.1.0/24`, which means that all IP addresses starting with `192.168.1` are in the same L2 broadcast domain, that is, connected to the same switch.

Devices that are in the same IP subnet communicate directly with each other via layer 2 "connectivity", there is no layer 3 routing happening.

IPTables is a mechanism that performs firewalling on routed packets between different subnets. It does not see any traffic that same subnet hosts send to each other.

If you want to install a firewall between the two hosts, there are a couple of options:

1. Move the hosts to different subnets (for example `192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.2.0/24`), and make the router route between the two subnets.
2. Install two different Ethernet segments, and configure your router as a bridge between the segments. Then one can configure IPTables to filter packets between the two Ethernet segments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I figured it out and I will try your suggestions.